# FacebookApi - An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to post an article using facebookapi and php. For one client when i call facebook api for getting page informations, i have an Oauth error "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user". It's working for all other client.

For getting informations from facebook page i try to call the url https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=accounts{access_token,link}&access_token=XXXX
I try to delete facebook cookie but without success. Anyone have a solution to refresh access_token from a user? I didn't see anything about that in the facebook doc.

Thanks,

Comment: debug the token and make sure it´s still valid: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: When i enter my token on this page, i get the app_id and the app_name. No mention, to an invalid token or an expired token

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing tokens is only possible on user interaction. If the user changed his password, for example, even an Extended Page Token becomes invalid.

I assume that happened, make sure the Token is still valid. Also, make sure not to post anything on a Page you don´t own without specific user consent.

About refreshing Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing

Comment: Thanks for your link. I try to refresh token to calling this url https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=224366798109457|u4AgF3vb7tl0_voYTFw5SMtuEj0&redirect_uri=http://sitedemo2.s20352.jvs51.2.atester.fr/izimedia-socialnetwork&client_id=224366798109457&client_secret=b2dbbf47dd12e9dfadc952902cdfe58a. 
The response is "An unknown error has occurred".
Do you see something wrong ?

Comment: that is an app token, why would you refresh it? it is always the same per app. also, do not post tokens in public, they are meant to be kept secret. you should change your app secret in the app settings now...